# Get Parent Account Name of Child Account in Power Bi

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerbi, parent-child, dynamics-365

Is there any way to get the Parent Account name of the Child account from D365 in Power BI without having to modify the data model?

In all reality, there are only 5 parent accounts that I need to create a slicer for and can create custom column via the GUIDs, but this is overall bad practice because need this dynamic in case I'm not around if they need to need more filters.

Comment: Please update your question to indicate the code you've tried and samples of your data, along with a mockup of expected output.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need a query or so to get only Parent Account who have child accounts linked to it.
If Yes you can query Accounts where `ParentAccountId Not null` and Linked to Account as 1:N `link-entity name="account" from="parentaccountid" to="accountid" link-type="inner" `

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a new column in existing dataset or a new dataset just to include the distinct parent accounts. Then use that as a slicer. So you have to touch the model. Or hard code the static GUIDs as a table (not recommended & not a good approach)

Not sure how you are fetching the dataset, using CRM endpoint or some SQL query, either way you can include the extra field by expanding (or inner join) the Account lookup to get Parent account lookup value as well.